# List of NoSQL databases that support Go

Tags: database, go, nosql

Is there a list of `NoSQL` database driver that supported by `Go`?
I only found list for `SQL` databases:

```
https://code.google.com/p/go-wiki/wiki/SQLDrivers
```

Comment: At http://github.com/tideland/godm you'll find my Redis client for Go.

Comment: I'm making the list `http://goo.gl/KJRCIr`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There's [`awesome-go`](https://github.com/avelino/awesome-go) which contains a list of [databases written in Go](https://github.com/avelino/awesome-go#database) and [database drivers for relational and non-relational databases](https://github.com/avelino/awesome-go#database-drivers).

Comment: The problem with awesome-go is that it's just a big list with no indication of which ones are any good or popular. They're all just in alphabetical order. This may have been useful back when there were only 1 or 2 in each category but now it's not very useful.

Answer (score 1):

Not that I'm aware of. Most(?) NoSQL databases have language agnostic API (REST/JSON, thrift, ...). The only one that I know of is [mgo](https://labix.org/mgo). Maybe you can start a list?

Comment: yes, let this post be the list ^_^

Comment: @Kokizzu I have to agree that a list must be created, except Stack Overflow does not allow this. SO don't want somebody to link to a website because it can be seen as advertising. Also, on SO it's also not allow to ask for a opinion, because everybody have a different opinion what seems easy for them, but can be difficult for the other. But i can understand your question, for example: Redis is also a database, if you look on the website, you can barely tell from the start that it is an NOSQL database.

Comment: I'm making the list here `http://goo.gl/KJRCIr`